# table sorter not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tablesorter

I'm trying to sort my table with table sorter and it is not working

```
<html>
<head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="blueStyle.css" type="text/css" media="print, projection, screen" />
    <script src="http://tablesorter.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="http://tablesorter.com/__jquery.tablesorter.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {      
        $("#myTable").tablesorter();
    }); 
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1"> 
<thead> 
<tr> 
    <th>Last Name</th> 
    <th>First Name</th> 
    <th>Email</th> 
    <th>Due</th> 
    <th>Web Site</th> 
</tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody> 
<tr> 
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>John</td> 
    <td>jsmith@gmail.com</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.jsmith.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>Bach</td> 
    <td>Frank</td> 
    <td>fbach@yahoo.com</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.frank.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>Doe</td> 
    <td>Jason</td> 
    <td>jdoe@hotmail.com</td> 
    <td>$100.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.jdoe.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>Conway</td> 
    <td>Tim</td> 
    <td>tconway@earthlink.net</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.timconway.com</td> 
</tr> 
</tbody> 
</table>
</body> 
 </html>
```

The styling seem to work, but there is not sorting.

This is what the table looks like at the moment.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to close a script tag `</script>` :

```
<script src="http://tablesorter.com/__jquery.tablesorter.min.js" type="text/javascript"/>
```

Correct markup :

```
<script src="http://tablesorter.com/__jquery.tablesorter.min.js" type="text/javascript"/></script>
```

I copied you code, added `</script>` and it works for me. Also jquery file from http://tablesorter.com/jquery-latest.js is really outdated (2008), consider using other cdn like //code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js or googleapis

Comment: even when i close properly nothing happens, same result

Comment: thats strange, can you paste you complete code so i can copy paste and check again?

Comment: I just copied you fixed code, didn't have to change anything, it works for me. With and without CSS

Comment: now that i changed my css link to website link it suddenly works, :S

Comment: I had the same problem and it turned out that I had missed to use the thead and tbody html tags in my table. Apparently tablesorter is dependent on them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize with tablesorter options. Here is example http://jsfiddle.net/dhana36/BKgue/184/

```
$('.tablesorter').tablesorter({
    // *** Appearance ***
    // fix the column widths
    widthFixed : true,
    // include zebra and any other widgets, options:
    // 'uitheme', 'filter', 'stickyHeaders' & 'resizable'
    // the 'columns' widget will require custom css for the
    // primary, secondary and tertiary columns
    widgets    : [ 'uitheme', 'zebra' ],
    // other options: "ddmmyyyy" & "yyyymmdd"
    dateFormat : "mmddyyyy",

    // *** Functionality ***
    // starting sort direction "asc" or "desc"
    sortInitialOrder : "asc",
    // These are detected by default,
    // but you can change or disable them
    headers : {
        // set "sorter : false" (no quotes) to disable the column
        0: { sorter: "text" },
        1: { sorter: "digit" },
        2: { sorter: "text" },
        3: { sorter: "url" }
    },
    // extract text from the table - this is how is
    // it done by default
    textExtraction : {
        0: function(node) { return $(node).text(); },
        1: function(node) { return $(node).text(); }
    },
    // forces the user to have this/these column(s) sorted first
    sortForce : null,
    // initial sort order of the columns
    // [[columnIndex, sortDirection], ... ]
    sortList : [[3,0]],
    // default sort that is added to the end of the users sort
    // selection.
    sortAppend : null,
    // Use built-in javascript sort - may be faster, but does not
    // sort alphanumerically
    sortLocaleCompare : false,
    // Setting this option to true will allow you to click on the
    // table header a third time to reset the sort direction.
    sortReset: false,
    // Setting this option to true will start the sort with the
    // sortInitialOrder when clicking on a previously unsorted column.
    sortRestart: false,
    // The key used to select more than one column for multi-column
    // sorting.
    sortMultiSortKey : "shiftKey",

    // *** Customize header ***
    onRenderHeader  : function() {
        // the span wrapper is added by default
        $(this).find('span').addClass('headerSpan');
    },
    // jQuery selectors used to find the header cells.
    selectorHeaders : 'thead th',

    // *** css classes to use ***
    cssAsc        : "headerSortUp",
    cssChildRow   : "expand-child",
    cssDesc       : "headerSortDown",
    cssHeader     : "header",
    tableClass    : 'tablesorter',

    // *** widget css class settings ***
    // column classes applied, and defined in the skin
    widgetColumns : { css: ["primary", "secondary", "tertiary"] },
    // find these jQuery UI class names by hovering over the
    // Framework icons on this page:
    // http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/
    widgetUitheme : { css: [
        "ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s", // Unsorted icon
        "ui-icon-arrowthick-1-s",   // Sort up (down arrow)
        "ui-icon-arrowthick-1-n"    // Sort down (up arrow)
        ]
    },
    // pick rows colors to match ui theme
    widgetZebra: { css: ["ui-widget-content", "ui-state-default"] },

    // *** prevent text selection in header ***
    cancelSelection : true,

    // *** send messages to console ***
    debug : false
});
```

Comment: The `widgetColumns` and `widgetUItheme` options are not part of the original version of tablesorter (v2.0.5); and deprecated in my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#deprecated)

Comment: Hmm, no, you don't need the options for it to work. It will work with default settings.